# Scikit Learn OneHotEncoder fit and transform Error: ValueError: X has different shape than during fitting

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Below is my code.

I know why the error is occurring during transform. It is because of the feature list mismatch during fit and transform.
How can i solve this? How can i get 0 for all the rest features?

After this i want to use this for partial fit of SGD classifier.

```html
Jupyter QtConsole 4.3.1
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Sep 21 2017, 18:29:43) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

input_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(fruit=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pine'], 
                             color=['Red', 'Orange','Green'],
                             is_sweet = [0,0,1],
                             country=['USA','India','Asia']))
input_df
Out[1]: 
    color country   fruit  is_sweet
0     Red     USA   Apple         0
1  Orange   India  Orange         0
2   Green    Asia    Pine         1



filtered_df = input_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
filtered_df.info()
# apply one hot encode
refreshed_df = pd.get_dummies(filtered_df)
refreshed_df
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
color       3 non-null object
country     3 non-null object
fruit       3 non-null object
is_sweet    3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes


Out[2]: 
   is_sweet  color_Green  color_Orange  color_Red  country_Asia  \
0         0            0             0          1             0   
1         0            0             1          0             0   
2         1            1             0          0             1   

   country_India  country_USA  fruit_Apple  fruit_Orange  fruit_Pine  
0              0            1            1             0           0  
1              1            0            0             1           0  
2              0            0            0             0           1  



enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(refreshed_df)

Out[3]: 
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)



new_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(fruit=['Apple'], 
                             color=['Red'],
                             is_sweet = [0],
                             country=['USA']))
new_df


Out[4]: 
  color country  fruit  is_sweet
0   Red     USA  Apple         0



filtered_df1 = new_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
filtered_df1.info()
# apply one hot encode
refreshed_df1 = pd.get_dummies(filtered_df1)
refreshed_df1
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 4 columns):
color       1 non-null object
country     1 non-null object
fruit       1 non-null object
is_sweet    1 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 112.0+ bytes



Out[5]: 
   is_sweet  color_Red  country_USA  fruit_Apple
0         0          1            1            1

enc.transform(refreshed_df1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-33a6a884ba3f> in <module>()
----> 1 enc.transform(refreshed_df1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in transform(self, X)
   2073         """
   2074         return _transform_selected(X, self._transform,
-> 2075                                    self.categorical_features, copy=True)
   2076 
   2077 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in _transform_selected(X, transform, selected, copy)
   1810 
   1811     if isinstance(selected, six.string_types) and selected == "all":
-> 1812         return transform(X)
   1813 
   1814     if len(selected) == 0:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in _transform(self, X)
   2030             raise ValueError("X has different shape than during fitting."
   2031                              " Expected %d, got %d."
-> 2032                              % (indices.shape[0] - 1, n_features))
   2033 
   2034         # We use only those categorical features of X that are known using fit.

ValueError: X has different shape than during fitting. Expected 10, got 4.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `pd.get_dummies()` you need [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) + OneHotEncoder which can store the original values and then use them on the new data.

Changing your code like below will give you required results.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
input_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(fruit=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pine'], 
                             color=['Red', 'Orange','Green'],
                             is_sweet = [0,0,1],
                             country=['USA','India','Asia']))

filtered_df = input_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

# This is what you need
le_dict = {}
for col in filtered_df.columns:
    le_dict[col] = LabelEncoder().fit(filtered_df[col])
    filtered_df[col] = le_dict[col].transform(filtered_df[col])

enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(filtered_df)
refreshed_df = enc.transform(filtered_df).toarray()

new_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(fruit=['Apple'], 
                             color=['Red'],
                             is_sweet = [0],
                             country=['USA']))
for col in new_df.columns:
    new_df[col] = le_dict[col].transform(new_df[col])

new_refreshed_df = enc.transform(new_df).toarray()

print(filtered_df)
      color  country  fruit  is_sweet
0      2        2      0         0
1      1        1      1         0
2      0        0      2         1

print(refreshed_df)
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]]

print(new_df)
      color  country  fruit  is_sweet
0      2        2      0         0

print(new_refreshed_df)
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

Comment: Works. I had this in mind erlier. But isn't the LabelEncoder to be used for Y target and not X features.? also milestone 20 of sklearn will release CategoricalEncoder. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @PunithRaj Yes it is meant for that. But in scikit we dont have any other utility to do that for multiplt features at a time (yet, there is [one present in development branch](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html) and may be available in next versions, which combines the LE and OHE into a single wrapper.) Unless that we have to use this workaround.

Comment: Thank you. I have Noted when we upgrade later we use the new feature.

Answer (score -1):

You encoder is fitted on `refreshed_df` which contains 10 columns and your `refreshed_df1` contains only 4, literally what it is reported in the error. You have either to delete the columns not appearing on your `refreshed_df1` or just fit your encoder to a new version of `refreshed_df` that only contains the 4 columns appearing in `refreshed_df1` .

Comment: I cant delete the feature columns because i want to use the output for SGDClassifer partial_fit. I need all the features but with 0

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892066/sgd-classifier-partial-fit-learning-with-different-dimensional-input-data . I was suggested to use transform

Comment: wouldn't it work if you add just empty columns and do `fill_na()` ?

Comment: Yes, it might work. but i was looking if something within sklearn.

Comment: Yes, `partial_fit` needs all the columns (features) but will work to train only on a subset of your data points (training example) that fits into your memory. Training on a different set of features means training a different model each time. Check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617356/sklearn-sgdclassifier-partial-fit